# services.php.volumes contains an invalid type, it should be an array

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need your help,
when I run the command:

`docker-compose up -d`

I get these errors:

```
services.php.volumes contains an invalid type, it should be an array
```

I use `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx/
    container_name: nginx-container
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - php
    volumes:
      - ./www/html/:/var/www/html/
  php:
    image: php:7.0-fpm
    container_name: php-container
    expose:
      – 9000
    volumes:
      – ./www/html/:/var/www/html/
```

Answer (score 2):

Woo.. Looks like you have copied from somewhere.

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx/
    container_name: nginx-container
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - php
    volumes:
      - ./www/html/:/var/www/html/
  php:
    image: php:7.0-fpm
    container_name: php-container
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - ./www/html/:/var/www/html/ # Only issue to this line other char has been append but look the same as `-`
```

Ref: I have attached the screenshots. Have a look.
[image]

Comment: thank you I fixed the issue, yes that is the problem.